# Alpaca sell order doesn't work and gives an error

Tags: python

I am getting this error when running my code.

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.alphavantage.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?function=STOCHF&symbol=HAL&interval=daily&fastkperiod=5&fastdperiod=3&apikey=DCH5W7COPS18WY69 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'www.alphavantage.co' doesn't match '*.eero.com'")))